# ORA-00911: invalid character - When running SQL dump

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a bunch of SQL which I need to execute, but Oracle is complaining with this error:

```
Error Message : ORA-00911: invalid character
Position      : 27
Statement     : (dump below)
```

I'm not sure what's causing this. I have tried removing the semicolon at the end as some answers suggested, but that's not doing the trick. I'm attempting to run this SQL dump on Laravel 5.2 with the `DB::unprepared()` method, like so:

```
DB::connection('oracle')->unprepared(File::get(base_path('/path/to/oracle_dump.sql')));
```

This is the SQL I'm trying to run:

```
DROP TABLE "MYUSERNAME"."POSTS";
DROP SEQUENCE "MYUSERNAME"."POST_SEQ";
CREATE TABLE POSTS
(
  ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), CONSTRAINT SYS_C004109 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  USING INDEX
  (
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C004109 ON POSTS (ID ASC)
      LOGGING
      TABLESPACE TEST_TABLSPACE
      PCTFREE 10
      INITRANS 2
      STORAGE
      (
        INITIAL 65536
        NEXT 1048576
        MINEXTENTS 1
        MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
      )
      NOPARALLEL
  )
  ENABLE
)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE TEST_TABLSPACE
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 1
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
NOPARALLEL
CREATE SEQUENCE POST_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20
CREATE TRIGGER POST_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT post_seq.NEXTVAL
INTO :new.id
FROM dual;
END;
```

I have used SQLDeveloper on Mac to get this dump.

Comment: I'm very new to Oracle. What is the first argument for `NUMBER`? Length? @KaushikNayak

Comment: Instead of `NUMBER(*, 0)` use just plain `NUMBER`

Comment: I did that and I'm getting the same message - no difference at all.

Comment: `NUMBER(*,0)` means the same as `INTEGER` @Kaushik; it's perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @Aborted I've been playing around with your statement a bit and I'm going to guess option#2 of https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00911.php. I got the same error as you until I retyped a few of the first lines, then I got a different error. I would retype it from scratch and try again.

Comment: If this were C#, I'd put semicolons (or anything that doesnt appear elsewhere in the file) after every distinct SQL statement, read the file into my app and split it on semicolons (or whatever) and then execute each statement singly on the DB - I've never succeeded in getting a multi-statement-split-by-semicolons string to execute in a single hit on the db, by packing them into a single command and executing it. I've always had to split it - maybe that's the Oracle drivers I've been using in C#, or maybe its a general limitation for oracle

Comment: ps;  SQLS, different beast. Multi statement commands like `INSERT INTO table blah values blah blah;SELECT @@scope_identity` are par for the course there, but in oracle, it's always been a single statement per commend/execute for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing each statement in a separate file, and do not close the statement with ";" once you have each in its file

You have 5 statement in the file "oracle_dump.sql". Have a separate file for each if you want to run them using a command like:

```
DB::connection('oracle')->unprepared(File::get(base_path('/path/to/<<file>>')));
```

Comment: I will try this out and report back.

Answer (score 5):

You should use ";" after each statement in the file "oracle_dump.sql".

```
DROP TABLE "MYUSERNAME"."POSTS";
DROP SEQUENCE "MYUSERNAME"."POST_SEQ";
CREATE TABLE POSTS
(
  ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), CONSTRAINT SYS_C004109 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  USING INDEX
  (
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C004109 ON POSTS (ID ASC)
      LOGGING
      TABLESPACE TEST_TABLSPACE
      PCTFREE 10
      INITRANS 2
      STORAGE
      (
        INITIAL 65536
        NEXT 1048576
        MINEXTENTS 1
        MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
      )
      NOPARALLEL
  )
  ENABLE
)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE TEST_TABLSPACE
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 1
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
NOPARALLEL;

CREATE SEQUENCE POST_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20;

CREATE TRIGGER POST_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT post_seq.NEXTVAL
INTO :new.id
FROM dual;
END;
```